# Using a function call as default parameter javascript

Tags: javascript, default-parameters, default-arguments

Help me understand why I can't do the following:

```js
function rgb(r = 0, g = 0, b = 0) {
  this.r = r % 255
  this.g = g % 255
  this.b = b % 255,
    this.str = function() {
      return `rgb(${this.r}, ${this.g}, ${this.b})`
    }
}

function rect(w, h, x, y, rgb = new rgb()) {
  this.dim = {
    w: w,
    h: h
  }
  this.pos = {
    x: x,
    y: y
  }
  this.rgb = rgb
}
```

I get the following error (when calling `rect()`):

> ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `rgb' before initialization

```js
function rgb(r = 0, g = 0, b = 0) {
  this.r = r % 255
  this.g = g % 255
  this.b = b % 255,
    this.str = function() {
      return `rgb(${this.r}, ${this.g}, ${this.b})`
    }
}

function rect(w, h, x, y, rgb = new rgb()) {
  this.dim = {
    w: w,
    h: h
  }
  this.pos = {
    x: x,
    y: y
  }
  this.rgb = rgb
}

const r = new rect(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Both `rgb` and `rect` are defined in the same file, and `rgb` is defined before `rect`.

Comment: rename `rgb` to something other than your `rgb` constructor function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable names are conflicting. You have a `rgb` function on the top level, but you also have a `rgb` parameter in `rect`'s parameter list. When inside a parameter list, when referencing a variable name, the interpreter will try to find what the variable name binds to - if the parameter list already has that variable name, it will reference that binding. So `new rgb()` is referencing the parameter `rgb`, which hasn't been initialized yet.

This isn't *exactly* what's happening, but the scope of a parameter list looks a *bit* like if the parameter names are declared with `let`, and then assigned values, eg the scope of

```
const fn = (a, b, c = 'bar') => {
  console.log('fn invoked');
};
```

is similar to:

```
const fn = (argA, argB, argC) => {
  let a;
  let b;
  let c;
  a = argA;
  b = argB;
  c = argC === undefined ? 'bar' : argC;
  fnBody(a, b, c);
};
const fnBody = (a, b, c) => {
  console.log('fn invoked');
}
```

So doing `rgb = new rgb()` is like

```
let rgb;
rgb = argRGB === undefined ? new rgb() : argRGB
//                               ^^^ reference to un-initialized variable
```

For similar reasons, you can do:

```js
const fn = (a, b = a) => {
  console.log(a, b);
};

fn('foo');
```

Also similarly, when declaring a variable, you can't reference the name of the variable you're declaring until the variable has finished initializing:

```js
const foo = null || foo;
```

Precise function names can help prevent bugs as well. Consider changing to something like:

```js
function makeColors(r = 0, g = 0, b = 0) {
  this.r = r % 255;
  this.g = g % 255;
  this.b = b % 255;
  this.str = function() {
    return `rgb(${this.r}, ${this.g}, ${this.b})`
  };
}

function rect(w, h, x, y, colors = new makeColors()) {
  this.dim = {
    w: w,
    h: h
  }
  this.pos = {
    x: x,
    y: y
  }
  this.colors = colors
}

const r = new rect(3, 4, 5, 6);
console.log(r);
```